# Azure Scheduler Long Running HTTP Action

Tags: azure-scheduler, azure-durable-functions

We have a Azure Function that is called from the Azure Scheduler.  It is a long running function.  We are using the Durable Functions Framework.  It is returning to the Azure Scheduler 202 Accepted, the Location for the callback to check status of the function.  For some reason it seems the Azure Scheduler is not calling back.  Based on the [documentation of "Limits"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-limits-defaults-errors#scheduler-quotas-limits-defaults-and-throttles) you are to implement the "HTTP asynchronous protocols" if you have an action that takes longer than 1 minute.  This is what we have done.  We have verified the response headers have Location and Retry-After with values.

From Docs:
There’s a static (not configurable) request timeout of 60 seconds for HTTP actions. For longer running operations, follow HTTP asynchronous protocols; for example, return a 202 immediately but continue working in the background.

Any one else encounter this behavior?

Comment: Are you able to get around this situation? I have a similar scenario where I need to check back the status of a long-running web job in a pipeline to run another web job. The first web job sends back 202 and moves to the next but my requirement is to wait till the first job is completed.